# running lint on ant app gives manifest error

Tags: android, ant

I have the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.mfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application  android:label="@string/app_name">
          <activity android:name=".Home" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

But when running lint,i get a warning 'Correctness': 'The  com.example.mfc.Home is not registered in the manifest

Issue: Ensures that Activities, Services and Content Providers are registered in the manifest
Id: Registered

Activities, services and content providers should be registered in the AndroidManifest.xml file using ,  and  tags.

If your activity is simply a parent class intended to be subclassed by other "real" activities, make it an abstract class.

[http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html]'

Whilst it is,and i have the class Home extending Activity:

```
package com.example.mfc;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import static us.monoid.web.Resty.*;
import us.monoid.web.Resty;
//import us.monoid.web.Resty.*;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
public class Home extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void Register(View arg0) {

        try{
             new Resty().json("http://app.zkn-web.com/register");

        /*  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Invalid email")
            .setMessage("Invalid email address")
             .show();
            */
            //Resty r = new Resty();
            //Object name = r.json("http://app.zkn-web.com/register").get("status");

        } catch(IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace(); // or what ever you want to do with it
        }

    }



}
```

I am also getting an error when trying to run the project,'android library projects cannot be launched'.Is it related to the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
  <activity android:name=".Home" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

to:

```
      <activity android:name="com.example.mfc.Home" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Is same,nothing changes.

Comment: can you post your logcat